# Find a string in a dynamic textbox JQUERY

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to search for the string 'sample' in a dynamic textbox but can't seem to make it work. What is wrong with my code?

```
var sentence =  document.getElementsByName('sentence[]');
for (i=0; i<sentence.length; i++)
    {
        if( sentence[i].indexOf('sample') != -1 )
            {
                alert("String Found");
                return false;
            }
    }
```

Comment: And where's your HTML?

Comment: `sentence[i]` is a dom element, you may want to use `sentence[i].value` like `sentence[i].value.indexOf('sample') != -1`

Comment: silly me,. that is what I'm missing.  the value. thx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sentence[i]` is a dom element, you may want to use `sentence[i].value` like

```
var sentence = document.getElementsByName('sentence[]');
for (i = 0; i < sentence.length; i++) {
    if (sentence[i].value.indexOf('sample') != -1) {
        alert("String Found");
        return false;
    }
}
```

jQuery

```
var valid = true;
$('input[name="sentence[]"]').each(function () {
    if (this.value.indexOf('sample') != -1) {
        valid = false;
        //to stop the iteration
        return false;
    }
});
if (!valid) {
    alert("String Found");
    return false;
}
```

or

```
var valid = $('input[name="sentence[]"]').filter(function () {
    return this.value.indexOf('sample') != -1
}).length == 0;
if (!valid) {
    alert("String Found");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What if I want to see if the string has parenthesis?

Answer (score 1):

This is listed as jQuery so I'm assuming we are allowed to use it?  From the looks of it I cannot tell when you are triggering this code.  You most likely want to do it on key up so it alerts you as soon as the word exists.

You need this:

```
$("[name='sentence']").keyup(function() {
    var text = $(this).val();
    if( text.indexOf("sample") >= 0 ) {
        alert("Found");
    }
});
```

You can see it working here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/45jEk/7/)

Comment: Sentence is an array of element names not an ID